# Webcam not working with Ubuntu 18

Tags: webcam, 18.10, camera

Can someone help me to solve this issue or to debug the issue?

I am not able to access my web camera on my Ubuntu 18 laptop. I removed and reinstalled cheese as well but no use. When I try to access the camera getting no device found.

Comment: You should give some more info. Is the webcam internal? Is it connected via USB? What device and programs are you using it with? do you have any logs to have a look at? Was the webcam never working or has something changed?

Comment: It was internal only. Earlier It was working fine and recently nothing I changed. What kind of logs that we can check?